# C++ assign values to a static array in a Class

Tags: c++, arrays, static

- I am new to C++. Compiler is complaining about below line:
  inv.inventory[0] = "Books". Please help me how can  I assign values
  to a static array in a Class.

// Class declaration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Items
{
private:
    string description;
public:
    Items()
    {
        description = ""; }

    Items(string desc)
    {
        description = desc;}

    string getDescription() { return description; }

};
class InventoryItems {
public:
    static Items inventory[5];

};
// main function
int main()
{
    const int NUM = 3;
    InventoryItems inv;
    inv.inventory[0] = "Books";

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        cout <<  inv.inventory[i].getDescription() << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I am getting below error:

> invMain.cpp:31: error: no match for operator= in InventoryItems::inventory[0] = "Books"
>   invMain.cpp:7: note: candidates are: Items& Items::operator=(const Items&)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong here:

```
static Items inventory[5];
```

`static` says that there is one and only one `inventory` for all `InventoryItems`. Unfortunately it doesn't allocate space for it with all compilers. OP could be seeing

> undefined reference to `InventoryItems::inventory'

You can allocate storage with

```
class InventoryItems {
public:
    static Items inventory[5];

};

Items InventoryItems::inventory[5]; // needs to be defined outside the class
```

The other big problem is you're trying to stuff the square peg in the round hole and getting something along the lines of

> error: no match for 'operator='

`"Books"` is a `const char *`, not an Items. `const char *` easily converts to a `string` because someone took the time to write functions that do the work. You will have to as well.

You can turn it into an Items and then assign it

```
inv.inventory[0] = Items("Books");
```

This creates a temporary `Items` and then after copying it destroys it. Bit expensive because you have a constructor and a destructor getting called just to copy one dang string.

You can also call do it like this:

```
InventoryItems::inventory[0] = Items("Books");
```

because all `InventoryItems` share the same `inventory`, you don't have to create an `InventoryItems` to get `inventory`.

If you don't want to create and destroy extra objects, you can write an assignment operator for Items that takes a string

```
Items & operator=(string desc)
{
    description = desc;
    return *this;
}
```

Now both

```
InventoryItems::inventory[0] = Items("Books");
```

and

```
InventoryItems::inventory[1] = "Pizza";
```

work.

You can also create a setter function in `Items`

```
void setDesc(string desc)
{
    description = desc;
}
```

Now you can for about the same cost as the `operator=`

```
InventoryItems::inventory[2].setDesc("Beer");
```

Which you chose it up to you. I personally like the setter in this case. It's more obvious what you are doing than the `=` and less expensive than the temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what the error is.  I compiled the same code in Visual Studio 2015 and got "binary '=': no operator found".

So the problem is that you haven't defined operator = for the Items class.  You need this because Items isn't equivalent to string, even though at this moment it only contains a string.